# Selenium Chrome Driver can't be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, selenium, automated-tests

I am trying to use Selenium web driver. I am using asp.net mvc. I have set up a very basic test. I'm basically just trying to open the browser.

```
 Imports NUnit.Framework
 Imports OpenQA.Selenium
 Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome
 Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox
 <TestFixture()>
 Public Class SeleniumEg

    Dim driverFF As IWebDriver
    Dim driverGC As IWebDriver
    Dim driverPath As String = "c:\chromedriver.exe"

 <Test()>
    Public Sub OpenBrowser()
        driverGC = New ChromeDriver(driverPath)
        driverGC.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.ie/")
    End Sub

 End Class
```

But when I run test i am getting this Error Message

Result Message:

> OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException : The file c:\chromedriver.exe\chromedriver.exe does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

I have also tried putting the driver in the soloution, but I am still getting driver does not exist. The error message seems to repeat the file name when saying its location:

> c:\chromedriver.exe\chromedriver.exe when it should be c:\chromedriver.exe

Comment: remove the filename from the path

Answer (score 2):

From the error message, I think the problem should be evident

> Result Message: OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException : The file c:\chromedriver.exe\chromedriver.exe does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

The ChromeDriver constructor (pardon me if I am not using the proper .NET terminologies, I am a Java guy) expects the directory in which the chromedriver.exe binary exists and not the actual location of the binary itself. See [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Chrome/ChromeDriver.cs#L95)

So please change

```
Dim driverPath As String = "c:\chromedriver.exe"
```

to

```
Dim driverPath As String = "c:\"
```

and see if that helps fix your issue.